# SparkSQL deallocate memory

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have ccala process which is using SparkSQl read data from .csv files process it and load it into table it was working properly, but after I add additional data to process it start failing with `java.io.IOException: No space left on device` I am using AWS.

```
  df_result_day_agg.write.format("jdbc").
    option("url", db_url_2).
    option("dbtable", output_table_name).
    option("user", db_user).
    option("password", db_pwd).
    option("truncate","true").
    option("batchsize", 5000).
    mode("overwrite").save()
```

I have several loads into DB  table, how I can delete variable which already finish load into DB table, so I can have free memory for processing other steps and do other loads?

Comment: Depends on you specific code and requirement. Sometimes it may not be possible to run your queries without loading everything. In some cases it is possible to breakdown your queries into steps and store intermediate results on disk, then use them in to build your final result.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh i am pretty new to scala and spark. as I can understand code its connecting to s3busket taking files create val df_raw_table thten doinsg . some joins o

Comment: then creates val df_result=sparkSession.sqlContext.sql(" SELECT") and then wright . into table then create new val df_result2 = select . and wtite it in DB